# Why am I getting "R drawable cannot be drawn"?

Tags: android, graphics, tabs

I'm basing my code off of [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html).

```
package com.Tabs.org;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class HelloTabWidget extends TabActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AlbumsActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_albums))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_songs))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    }
}
```

The error is that the R drawable ic_tabs_songs/albums/artists cannot be drawn. `setContentView(R.layout.main);` also cannot be drawn. I'm sure I got the graphics in the right folder, `res/drawable/ldpi folder`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning the project?

Project -> Clean

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, the tutorial you mentioned has some mistakes. I also followed your mentioned tutorial and solve the problems.
In short:
Create a folder named drawable just under 'res' folder.[image]

and my code works fine

```
        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Banks.class);
    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("banks").setIndicator("Banks",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Just another note, you will find that, in the tutorial, they didn't add the other two activities in the manifest file which you must add by yourself.

```
        <activity android:name="com.dbz.dbzatmactivities.Banks"
        android:label="Banks"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.dbz.dbzatmactivities.Atms"
        android:label="ATMs"></activity>
```

Here, Banks and Atms are the name of my other tab activities.